# ENUM type in SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, enums, sqlalchemy

I'm using [SQLAlchemy core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/) with a postgresql database and I would like to add the **ENUM** type to my table definition. According to the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-enum.html), the ENUM type must be defined prior to the table being created:

```sql
CREATE TYPE gender_enum AS ENUM ('female', 'male');

CREATE TABLE person (
  name VARCHAR(20),
  gender gender_enum
);
```

The problem is when I'm creating the table definition. After reading the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM) I couldn't find any implementation examples. I've tried something like this but it didn't work:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM

person = Table('user_profile', metadata,
    Column('name', String(20)),
    Column('gender', ENUM('female', 'male'))
);
```

How it must be done?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to import Enum from sqlalchemy and add a name to it. It should work like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Enum

person = Table("user_profile", metadata,
    Column("name", String(20)),
    Column("gender", Enum("female", "male", name="gender_enum", create_type=False))
);
```

Comment: For this to work with postgres for me, I had to `from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM`

Comment: Well which is it? OP said `postgreql.ENUM` didn't work, comment says it does work. Is there a version or driver distinction that causes the discrepancy?

Comment: Why: `create_type=False`?

Comment: `create_type` isn't actually useful here - that's for `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM`. In a nutshell - use `sqlalchemy.Enum` if you want to define the enum type *and create it* during a `create_table` command. If you want to use an existing type for a new table during creation, use the `dialects.postgresql.ENUM` one with `create_type = False`

Comment: In case anyone is using specific schemas, I had the same issue and I was able to solve it using `from sqlalchemy import Enum` and for the schema I was able to pass `schema=<schema_name>` to `Enum`. `Enum` type documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum.__init__

Comment: thank you @lv10 - adding `schema=<schema_name>` to the Enum fixes it for me: also for table creation, it now properly issues a CREATE TYPE.

Answer (score 38):

@Tim's answer is definitely correct but I wanted to offer the way I setup my ENUMs.

In my models.py I will create the values as tuples

`skill_levels = ('Zero', 'A little', 'Some', 'A lot')`

Then I will create a skill_level_enum variable and assign it an ENUM class with the skill level values as args.

`skill_level_enum = ENUM(*skill_levels, name="skill_level")`

In my table model then I pass in the skill_level_enum

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    skill_level = db.Column(skill_level_enum)
```

I have found this makes my code a lot cleaner and I'm able to make updates to the skill_levels at the top of my file rather than scanning my models for the right thing to update.

Comment: That is correct, you can define the enum once and use it wherever you need to.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Python's native enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) as the input for a column type:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM as pgEnum
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class errorTypeEnum(Enum):
    videoValidation = 'videoValidation'
    audioValidation = 'audioValidation'
    subtitleValidation = 'subtitleValidation'

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Error(db.Model):
    serviceID = db.Column(db.String(20), primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=False, nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(pgEnum(errorTypeEnum), unique=False, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

The code below worked for me on SQLAlchemy 1.3.11 and Postgres 12.0.

You must first create the Enum type in postgres before creating the user table. This can be done directly through sql statement.

```
CREATE TYPE permission AS ENUM ('READ_ONLY', 'READ_WRITE', 'ADMIN', 'OWNER');
```

Then set up the project model

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy    

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model): 
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)   
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    access = db.Column(db.Enum('READ_ONLY', 'READ_WRITE', 'ADMIN', 'OWNER', name="permission"))
```