# Defining SQLAlchemy enum column with Python enum raises "ValueError: not a valid enum"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to follow [this example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html) to have an enum column in a table that uses Python's `Enum` type.  I define the enum then pass it to the column as shown in the example, but I get `ValueError: <enum 'FruitType'> is not a valid Enum`.  How do I correctly define a SQLAlchemy enum column with a Python enum?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import enum

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class FruitType(enum.Enum):
    APPLE = "Crunchy apple"
    BANANA = "Sweet banana"

class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    fruit_type = db.Column(enum.Enum(FruitType))
```

```
File "why.py", line 32, in <module>
    class MyTable(db.Model):
  File "why.py", line 34, in MyTable
    fruit_type = db.Column(enum.Enum(FruitType))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 330, in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 642, in __new__
    raise ValueError("%s is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__name__))
ValueError: <enum 'FruitType'> is not a valid Enum
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The column type should be [`sqlalchemy.types.Enum`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum).  You're using the Python `Enum` type again, which was valid for the value but not the column type. Back in 2016, when the question was written, this was necessary:

```
class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    fruit_type = db.Column(db.Enum(FruitType))
```

However, this is not the case anymore.

Comment: It raises: TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

Comment: @AmirShabani did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Chris I use flask sqlalchemy like this: db.Column(db.Enum("AutoService", "Insurance", "CarWash", name="service_category"))

Comment: @AmirShabani thanks, thats what i ended up doing, just unfortunate that you have to maintain it in two different locations if you want a class enum to be used elsewhere in your code

Comment: @AmirShabani @Chris Please note that although the column type should be [`sqlalchemy.types.Enum`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum), the class which represent the enum should inherit from Python's `enum.Enum` - ([Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) or [enum34](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/)) - you can see the [example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum)

Comment: FYI - This causes errors in Flask Admin, I ended up using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33042283/50348