# new value in class Enum rejected by database

Tags: python, mysql, enums, sqlalchemy

I have this class in my models.py file:

```
class DepartmentCategory(Enum):
    """The various categories of departments"""
    committee = 'Committee'
    subcommittee = 'Subcommittee'
```

that is used in a selectfield for my form. All works well but when I add a new value to the Enum class eg:

```
class DepartmentCategory(Enum):
    """The various categories of departments"""
    general = 'General'
    committee = 'Committee'
    subcommittee = 'Subcommittee'
```

saving the new value the database fails and no errors are shown both in terminal and browser. I had already numerously migrated(flask db migrate) and upgraded(flask db upgrade) my database but problem not solved. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `enum34`. I found `flask_migrate` can not detecte changes while i am using `enum` on Python3-x. Then i saw the comments in this question [Defining SQLAlchemy enum column with Python enum raises "ValueError: not a valid enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136112/defining-sqlalchemy-enum-column-with-python-enum-raises-valueerror-not-a-valid)

> pip install enum34

Note: keep using `import enum`, `import enum34` is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

you need to migrate your db definition, e.g. using https://pypi.org/project/alembic/

Comment: if you mean running *flask db migrate* then *flask db upgrade*, that I already did. I am using *Flask-Migrate*.