# Access Enum Value from a Database Record in Python / Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, enums, sqlalchemy

I have a class as such:

```
class VoteEnum(enum.Enum):
    like = "LIKE"
    dislike = "DISLIKE"
    abstain =  "ABSTAIN"
```

I have a database which stores these votes as such:

```
class MyVotes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_votes"
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, default=lambda: str(uuid4()))
    item = db.Column(db.String,  nullable=False),
    vote = db.Column(db.Enum(VoteEnum))

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps({
            "id":self.id,
            "item":self.item,
            # I want to print the value of vote?
    )}
```

When retrieving values from sqlalchemy *(in flask)* and printing, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type MyVotes is not JSON serializable

***Perhaps there a way to call in my sqlalchemy request? Maybe the class method?*** I appreciate any help folks can provide.

Comment: Possible answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6104825/208880 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36136344/208880.

Comment: I wish they solved my problem @EthanFurman – sadly, am still getting the error.

Comment: Maybe this one?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/5022066/208880

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar situation. Here is how you should do it. Enums have name and value.

```
def __str__(self):
    return json.dumps({
        'id': self.id,
        'item': self.item,
        'vote': self.vote.name
    })
```