# psycopg2.ProgrammingError on Enum type in Flask (database) database migration

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

When running a migration on my Flask app's postgres database I get the following psycopg2 error on an Enum type:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 8753d3c9dbd1, empty message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jul/.miniconda3/envs/audiolabeling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/jul/.miniconda3/envs/audiolabeling/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: type "feedbacktype" already exists
```

I tried to delete the alembic_version table and the migrations folder and rerun flask db init/migrate/upgrade, with no success.

I had to drop the database entirely to solve the issue.

Is there any way to not recreate types when they already exist ?

**models.py**

```
from audiolabeling import db
import enum


class FeedBackType(enum.Enum):
    NONE = "none"
    HIDDENIMAGE = "hiddenImage"

class Task(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feedback = db.Column(db.Enum(FeedBackType))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably pretty late for an answer but will still try to post it for someone else looking for this in the future. (As I was)

There's also a `create_type` kwarg for `postgresql.ENUM`. which is used to set the schema for an enum type column in the alembic migration script.

Here's what my new column definition looks like. (Which uses existing an existing enum)

```py
sa.Column('ActionType', postgresql.ENUM('Primary', 'Secondary', name='actiontype', create_type=False), nullable=True),
```

This will now use the existing enum for the new column without creating a new one.

I'm using `SQLAlchemy==1.1.1` and `alembic==0.8.8` in my requirements file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `feedback = db.Column(db.Enum(["NONE", "HIDDENIMAGE"]))` to replace your code.

Comment: What if I want to use this Enum in several tables ?

Comment: You can define a list which consist of the values to construct the enum type. And unpack it in where you want to define a enum type field.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The below does NOT work with Alembic. Same issue is here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/566

Use   `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM` instead of `db.Enum` when creating the column.

`ENUM` has the optional parameter `create_type`, which should be set to `False`.

Like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM

...

class Task(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feedback = db.Column(ENUM(FeedBackType, create_type=False))

def __repr__(self):
    return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```