# How should I declare enums in SQLAlchemy using mapped_column (to enable type hinting)?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to use `Enums` in SQLAlchemy 2.0 with `mapped_column`.  So far I have the following code (taken from another question):

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM as pgEnum
import enum

class CampaignStatus(str, enum.Enum):
    activated = "activated"
    deactivated = "deactivated"

CampaignStatusType: pgEnum = pgEnum(
    CampaignStatus,
    name="campaignstatus",
    create_constraint=True,
    metadata=Base.metadata,
    validate_strings=True,
)

class Campaign(Base):
    __tablename__ = "campaign"

    id: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    created_at: Mapped[dt.datetime] = mapped_column(default=dt.datetime.now)
    status: Mapped[CampaignStatusType] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
```

However, that gives the following error upon the construction of the  `Campaign` class itself.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in <module>
    class Campaign(Base):
...
AttributeError: 'ENUM' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

Any hint about how to make this work?

The response from [ENUM type in SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894257/enum-type-in-sqlalchemy-with-postgresql) does not apply as I am using version 2 of SQLAlchemy and those answers did not use `mapped_column` or `Mapped` types. Also, removing `str` from `CampaignStatus` does not help.

Comment: Moreover `class CampaignStatus(str, enum.Enum): ...` will not work because this is mixing two different classes with different metaclass - you shouldn't try inherit from two completely unrelated classes unless you know exactly what you are doing.  Just do `class CampaignStatus(enum.Enum): ...`

Comment: Thanks but I have just added str because on another SO question someone mentioned that made it work for him, which is not my case. Even removing str does not help

Comment: I had to set up your environment manually (as you didn't provide a complete `Traceback`); it took time to deduce that `status: Mapped[CampaignStatusType] = mapped_column(nullable=False)` being the cause - changing this to the previous method of defining columns `status = sqlalchemy.Column(CampaignStatusType, nullable=False)` (e.g. from the linked duplicate) still works.  In any case with the clarification I reopened the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The crux of the issue relating to `__mro__` causing the `AttributeError` is that `CampaignStatusType` is not a class, but rather an instance variable of type `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM` (using [`pyright`](https://pypi.org/project/pyright/) may verify this - given that it complains about `Mapped[CampaignStatusType]` being an "Illegal type annotation: variable not allowed unless it is a type alias").  As a test, replacing the type annotation for `status` with `Mapped[CampaignStatus]` does resolve the issue (and `pyright` reports no errors), but that does not hook the column type to the enum with postgresql dialect that is desired.

So the only way around this while using the dialect specific enum type is to use the [non-annotated](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#declarative-table-with-mapped-column) construct:

```py
    status = mapped_column(CampaignStatusType, nullable=False)
```

However, if type annotation is still desired, i.e. whatever being `Mapped` must be a type, and that `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM` (which was imported as `pgEnum`) is the underlying type for the instance `CampaignStatusType`, it may be thought that the following might be a solution

```py
    # don't do this erroneous example despite it does run
    status: Mapped[sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ENUM] = mapped_column(
        CampaignStatusType,
        nullable=False,
    )
```

While it works, it does NOT actually reflect what will be represented by the data, so **DO NOT** actually do that.  Moreover, it only works because the type annotation is ignored when the specific column type is passed, so putting anything in there will work while having an invalid type.

Now, given that SQLAlchemy is now 2.0 (as the question explicitly want this newer version), perhaps reviewing the documentation and see now [native enums](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#native-enums-and-naming) should be handled now.

Adapting the examples in the documentation, the following MVCE may now be derived, using all the intended keyword arguments that was passed to the PostgreSQL dialect specific ENUM type passed generic `sqlalchemy.Enum` instead (aside from `metadata=Base.metadata` as that's completely superfluous):

```py
from typing import Literal
from typing import get_args
from sqlalchemy import Enum
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

CampaignStatus = Literal["activated", "deactivated"]

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Campaign(Base):
    __tablename__ = "campaign"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    status: Mapped[CampaignStatus] = mapped_column(Enum(
        *get_args(CampaignStatus),
        name="campaignstatus",
        create_constraint=True,
        validate_strings=True,
    ))
```

Note the use of [`typing.get_args`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171103/) on `CampaignStatus` and splat it to the `Enum` here as opposed to what the official examples have done in repeating themselves.  Now to include the usage:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def main():
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost/postgres')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    session.add(Campaign(status='activated'))
    session.add(Campaign(status='deactivated'))
    session.commit()

    s = 'some_unvalidated_string'
    try:
        session.add(Campaign(status=s))
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        print("failed to insert with %r" % s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above will produce `failed to insert with 'some_unvalidated_string'` as the output, showing that unvalidated strings will not be inserted, while validated strings that are mapped to some enum are inserted without issues.  Moreover, `pyright` will not produce errors (though honestly, this is not necessarily a good metric because type hinting in Python is still fairly half-baked, as `pyright` did not detect the erroneous example as an error in the very beginning no matter what went inside `Mapped`, but I digress).

Viewing the newly created entities using `psql`

```text
postgres=# select * from campaign;
 id |   status    
----+-------------
  1 | activated
  2 | deactivated
(2 rows)
```

```text
postgres=# \dt campaign;
                                Table "public.campaign"
 Column |      Type      | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
--------+----------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id     | integer        |           | not null | nextval('campaign_id_seq'::regclass)
 status | campaignstatus |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "campaign_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

postgres=# \dT+ campaignstatus;
                                             List of data types
 Schema |      Name      | Internal name  | Size |  Elements   |  Owner   | Access privileges | Description 
--------+----------------+----------------+------+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------------
 public | campaignstatus | campaignstatus | 4    | activated  +| postgres |                   | 
        |                |                |      | deactivated |          |                   | 
(1 row)
```

The enum of course cannot be dropped without dropping the `campaign` table:

```text
postgres=# drop type campaignstatus;
ERROR:  cannot drop type campaignstatus because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  column status of table campaign depends on type campaignstatus
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

So the enum more or less behaves as expected despite only using generic SQLAlchemy types, without needing dialect specific imports.

Comment: Sorry I have been traveling and I have not been able to test this thoroughly but so far it builds ok. In a couple of days I will try to test the execution and come back to let you know if it is ok

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I did not forget about your help. I have managed to find time to test this properly and indeed it seems to work. Again thank you for the help and great explanation.  Have a great day!